# How I Get the total ItemCount of all the Document Present in my sharepoint 2010 Document Library using azax call

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library

I want to call by a ASMX Webservice at the time of page load . it comes but very late in my page

Comment: Please post your code.